# Why does running Visual Studio Code from the Run dialog open a cmd window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd.exe

I observe that when I run `code` in the Run dialog, a cmd window opens, while if I run it via double click or via Start menu there isn't any such a window.

[image]

Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open it from Start menu, you're launching a shortcut to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe` GUI app. You can verify that by going to the location of the shortcut and checking its properties.

Typing `code`, on the other hand, launches `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code`, which is a binary file that works in CLI and which launches the GUI app after paring any arguments, switches etc.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin` is added to the `PATH` env var, hence e.g. run box finds and executes that binary file.